# Initiating multiple widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Imagine this as the main.py:

```
class Widget1(Button):
    pass

class Widget2(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

And inside the .kv file:

```
<Widget1>:
    Button:

<Widget2>:
    Image:
```

How do I initialize both `Widget1` and `Widget2` inside the main file? Creating separate `App`s doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
class Widget1(Button)
    pass

class Widget2(ButtonBehavior, Image)
    pass

class MyMain(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyMain()

MyApp().run()
```

and in your kivy

```
<MyMain>:
    <Widget1>:
        Button:

    <Widget2>:
        Image:
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put another `Button` and `Image` inside a widget that *inherits* it? Seems to me like this:

> create button → place another button into that button widget

You don't want that. And definitely not creating rules inside a rule - something hardly similar in python:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        ...
    ...
```

There are usecases for that, but this isn't it. :P Also I don't see a point with creating it like this:

```
<MyMain>:
    <Widget1>:
        Button:

    <Widget2>:
        Image:
```

because you *have to* connect it with python file this way(it expects a class). Something else would be `<MyWidget@Button>:`

However, there's a little bit easier way to do it and it doesn't require additional (in this case empty) class:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

class Widget1(Button):
    pass

class Widget2(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MyApp(BoxLayout, App):
    def build(self):
        self.add_widget(Widget1())
        self.add_widget(Widget2())
        return self

MyApp().run()
```

This way you don't need to create another class just as a placeholder, which is quite handy if you work with something small. I'm not sure about inheriting order in `MyApp`, but it seems to work both for `BoxLayout, App` and `App, BoxLayout` cases.